# Error reading csv to convert time to timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

I have the following csv structure file.

Time

01/01/2010 00:00

01/01/2010 00:10

...
Both consumption and consumption2 files are the same (the only difference is the row number). The first column corresponds to the time format 01/01/2010  00:00:00. The following 199 columns correspond to demand values. I believe that the problem comes from the first column format.

here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
data=pd.read_csv('Consumption.csv',header=None, sep='\n')#, sep='\t')
data.head()
data['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(data['Time'])
plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(10,5))
data.Timestamp.plot() #Plotting the newly added timestamp column
plt.xlabel('Reading Count')
plt.ylabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

I tried to convert time to timestamp but I cannot plot the data as I get the following error:
I seems a problem from timestamp. Do you have any suggestion on how could be possible to solve th problem?

```
1 #Converting time to timestamp ( a datetime object)
----> 2 data['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(data['Time'])
3 
4 # Ensuring there are no temporal gaps
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/python3b/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
2645 try:
-> 2646 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
2647 except KeyError:
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()
KeyError: 'Time'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-9b4c885821b2> in <module>
1 #Converting time to timestamp ( a datetime object)
----> 2 data['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(data['Time'])
3 
4 # Ensuring there are no temporal gaps
5 plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(10,5))
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/python3b/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
2798 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
2799 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
2801 if is_integer(indexer):
2802 indexer = [indexer]
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/python3b/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
2646 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
2647 except KeyError:
-> 2648 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
2649 indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
2650 if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()
KeyError: 'Time'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct column name?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The first column is named 'Time' and it contains the value format as 01/01/2010 00:00. The second column is named H1, third H2, etc. I really don´t know how to solve the issue. the complete cvs file is here: https://github.com/charlicruz/Energy-Demand. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your code to import the datafile is incorrect (IMHO). You can also convert the Time column to datetime directly to save some steps

```
data=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/charlicruz/Energy-Demand/master/consumption.csv',
                 header=0, sep=';', 
                 parse_dates=[0], index_col=0,
                 decimal=','
                )
data.plot(y='Household 1')
```

[image]